# Value setting to null when debuging, not so much when running

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have category that can have child-categories/root-category. When I change my root category to some other category it works but when I try to set it to `null` (to make it root category) it does not change anything. I'm using code-first approach if that makes any difference.

Here is code where I explicitly state that `category.RootCategory = null` but it does not work, root category still is what is set previously.

### Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Category c, int? rootCategoryID)
{
    var category = _db.Categories.Where(x => x.ID == c.ID).Single();

    if (TryUpdateModel(category))
    {
        cateogry.RootCategory = null;
            _db.SaveChanges();
        return Content(Infrastructure.Helpers.SerializeObject(category));
    }

    return Redirect("/admin/category");
}
```

### Model

```
public class Category
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    virtual public Category RootCategory { get; set; }
    virtual public ICollection<Category> ChildCategories { get; set; }
}
```

### Update

Very strange behavior. When I debug it and go step by step slowly it updates it, when I don't debug it or run fast it is not updating. I have no clue why it is like that.

Comment: @SidharthMudgal well if I see json output instead of redirect then it did, otherwise I would be redirected to `/admin/category`.

Comment: Strange. How are you testing it?

Comment: 1. JSON output shows that RootCategory is still set; 2. I just go back and refresh page and it did not change. :(

Comment: Could you try putting a breakpoint at `cateogry.RootCategory = null;` and checking what happens each statement after it?

Comment: it works then when I run slowly, when I step through lines fast it won't work. WTF?!?! 0.o

Comment: Does category also have a rootCategoryId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway I added `public int? RootCategoryID { get; set; }` to my model and now I can just edit it like so.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Category c)
{
    var cateogry = _db.Categories.Where(x => x.ID == c.ID).Single();

    if (TryUpdateModel(cateogry))
    {
        cateogry.UpdatedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return Redirect("/admin/category");
}
```

It works now, but still have no idea why it did work without RootCategoryID on runtime and did on debug.

Comment: This might have been a side effect of lazy loading and debugger. If a navigation property is displayed in the Wath/Locals window it is being evaluated which may trigger lazy loading and therefore the state of your program is actually different when you run with debugging and when the debugger is not attached. Try removing all properties/objects from watch window and close auto and locals windows and see if the behavior is now the same.